# Inject JS code that excute the extension's code when a button on a website is clicked

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to execute another function when a button on a website is clicked. I wonder to know if this is possible with chrome extension functionality and is this ethical to make and it's good to know that the code that I execute with my extension has many additions to the same website code?

Comment: You need to provide more information. Of course what you are describing is possible. Is this extension entirely for your own usage? Not sure why you are referring to ethics?..

Comment: No I will publish it on store, it will add an addition to the site I want to add the extension for, I talk about ethics, because it will change the main behavior of the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this just add an event listener to the element you try to manipulate in your content script:

```
document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
   evt.preventDefault(); // prevent default action of the button
   otherStuff();
}
```

Also don't forget to add this content script to your [`manifest.json`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html)

If it fits the purpose of the extension it's ethical of course, therefore we have JavaScript :).

Comment: preventDefault doesn't prevent the original script of the site. I use 
  $(this).clearQueue(); after preventDefault  and it doesn't prevent the excution.